# Making a form on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to make a form linked to my message object, so in my new.html.erb view for messages i have written:

```
<%= form_for @message, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :subject %>
    <%= f.text_field :recipient %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately, when I run rails s to test it out I get

```
undefined method `subject' for #<Message id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

1: <%= form_for @message, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
2:     <%= f.text_field :subject %>
3:     <%= f.text_field :recipient %>
4:     <%= f.text_area :body %>
5:     <%= f.submit "Create" %>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: you have a typo: `text_fied` should be `text_field` on the second line

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my question... I've updated it above. Thanks

Comment: Reading the error message goes a long way. Can you post the updated error message?

Comment: It `Message` model, there is no subject attribute? `<Message id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

Comment: are you sure that the `Message` model has the attribute `subject`?

Comment: Is the migration up to date? Otherwise it should not raise some kind of error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

undefined method `subject' for #

According to that message it shows that subject is not an attribute of message. Maybe you need to run your migrations?